# Writing into a current entry instead of creating a new one in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a document form and write the document location into the user's current database entry, it keeps creating a new entry when I attempt to do so, aswell as if I attempt to use pk=p in the part that writes the data it will overwrite the entire entry.

views.py

```
** I import everything here **

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def list(request):
# Handle file upload
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        p = request.user.pk
        newdoc = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=p)
        newdoc = CustomUser(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
        # I also attempted the following which overwrit the entire user
        # newdoc = CustomUser(pk=p, docfile = request.FILES['docfile']))
        newdoc.save()

        # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
else:
    form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

current_user = request.user

# Render list page with the documents and the form
return render(request, 'list.html', {'form': form,'pk':current_user.pk})
```

models.py for the user

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
 pass

 def __str__(self):
     return self.email

 docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='static/users/',)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='max. 42 megabytes'
)
```

Comment: Just set the attribute, so `newdoc.docfile = request.FILES['docfile']`, instead of `newdoc = ...`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem
This for some reason prevents the files from being uploaded

Comment: Please show the definition of DocumentForm. Is it a ModelForm?

Comment: nevermind, after throwing things at the code and seeing what sticks I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks willem, you was the one that solved my last problem wasn't you?
You should create a answer so I can set it as the answer.